# Why were housing cooperatives prohibited in The Netherlands until 2015?

Tags: netherlands, housing

In a [housing cooperative](https://www.wohnungsbaugenossenschaften.de/genossenschaften/how-cooperatives-work) the residents of an apartment block jointly own the building as a cooperative and pay rent to their own organisation, which is democratically controlled by all residents/members.  This is apparently an increasingly popular construct to organise affordable middle class housing in expensive cities.  In The Netherlands those were apparently quite common starting in the 19th century, but [prohibited after World War II until 2015](https://www.woonbond.nl/beleid-belangen/zelfbeheer/wooncooperaties-en-wetgeving) (source in Dutch only, my apologies); instead, most tenants traditionally rent from housing corporations/building associations (Dutch: *woningbouwvereniging*).  What is the rationale for banning housing cooperatives?

Comment: What *was* the rational (given that they are now legal).  I'd guess it was that these tended to be a breeding ground for radical politics.... but finding out the motivations of the Dutch government in the 1940s isn't going to be easy...

Comment: @JamesK I was considering whether to ask here or on [History.SE], settled for here because whatever rationale they had might still apply today.

Comment: As a German trying to wrap my head around the difference between the housing associations and the cooperatives (possibly because something called Wohnungsbauverein/-vereinigung typically is a Genossenschaft = cooperative): who is associated in a Dutch housing association?

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX I find it hard to translate the difference to English or German, but by housing cooperative (_wooncoöperatie_) I mean what I think is in Germany a _Wohnungsbaugenossenschaft_, whereas Dutch _woningbouwvereniging_ literally means _Wohnungsbauverein_ or _building association_, but are today large professional not-for-profit landlords that I think rarely have actual members anymore... it's all very complicated and I don't understand it myself. I think they have a special status in the law that is distinct from corporation, cooperative, foundation, or association.

Comment: There is quite a lot of historical information here:
https://www.canonsociaalwerk.eu/nl_vhv/details.php?cps=20&canon_id=489

Answer (score 4):

In the past, cooperatives in the field of housing were common in the Netherlands, but after the Second World War they were banned. During the reconstruction, a lot of government subsidies went to public housing. The legislator feared that the members of housing cooperatives would cash in on the accumulated capital, for example by selling their houses built with subsidies. Instead of the cooperative, only housing associations and foundations were allowed to be active in public housing.

And now that it is possible there are still no guarantees because there are a lot of rules and regulations to abide by to block the abuse of subsidies that are given.

Comment: Interesting and plausible, would you have sources that confirm this?

Comment: @gerrit I had this discussion with a friend on FB a few years ago shortly before it got changed. We used links but none of them seem to be working anymore. All now just redirect to homepages that are only stuffed with information about Covid.